# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. with react useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I have 2-3 documents in firestore database, i am trying to read this and display on a list with following code.

```
function Todo(props){
    return(
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <ListItemText key={props.data.todo.id}/>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    );
}
```

but react always complain that `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

but i tried key attribute on li element

Comment: Where is the part you are genereting list with map

Comment: Assuming your loop return `<ListItem></ListItem>`, your key should pass to `ListItem` not to the `ListItemText`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016001/react-warning-encountered-two-children-with-the-same-key)

Comment: No, i tried by adding key to ListItem, but react still complain about unique key

Comment: The error you've got appears when you use `map` or multiple children for one element. There is nothing like this in the snippet you included

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you simplified your code, removing the `map` (because as it is, there's no problem with "Each child in a list").

Anyway: the `ListItemText` is not the child, `ListItem` is, and `ListItem` should have the `key` property.

Comment: I tried this, not working for me